# Elasticsearch: find nested document by min value of its field and apply another filters on this document

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a document (user) and a list of nested documents (orders) in Elastic. I need to find a user with an order satisfied a bunch of conditions: the status of order should have some specific value, its id should start with some specific digits and its date should be the min in the list of user's orders.

I didn't find a way how to do this. Is it possible?
Please help ...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you please share some sample data and your expected search result ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.